# Firebase database Query StartAt() Not Working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

**So I have been trying to paginate my Recyclerview so whenever the recyclerView reaches to the bottom of the screen I will call addNewPosts method**

Here the **lastItemId** is the last id of the view that has been retrieved from the firebase.

I checked it, it is not null and giving the correct node that is at the bottom of the screen.

**Method**

```
private void addNewPost(String lastItemId) {

    Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Admin").child(mAuth.getUid()).child("INSTITUTE")
            .child("PROGRAMMES").orderByChild("programmeName");


    ref.startAt(lastItemId).limitToFirst(6).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            StyleableToast.makeText(Programme_students.this, "ca", R.style.exampleToast).show();

            // retreiving the data of hte students
            String _icon = snapshot.child("PROGRAMMEINFORMATION").child("programmeIcon").getValue().toString();
            String _programmeName = snapshot.child("PROGRAMMEINFORMATION").child("programmeName").getValue().toString().toUpperCase();
            String _programmeCode = snapshot.child("PROGRAMMEINFORMATION").child("programmeCode").getValue().toString();


            // creating a object of students
            ProgrammeHelper programmeHelperzzz = new
                    ProgrammeHelper(_icon, _programmeName, _programmeCode);

            //adding the stuents to the global variable
            programmesfromdatabase.add(programmeHelperzzz);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            programme_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            settinglistviewwwwwww();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

**So there is a Custom toast called Stylabletoast  just to confirm I kept it there so the toast is not being shown the Method is not being called when I keep the StartAt() function**

**As soon i remove the StartAt() the code works it gives me all the new posts but it duplicates Because it is starting from the start**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have used `orderByChild("programmeName")` in your query, `startAt()` will now set the `"programmeName"` value to start at, not the key as you are expecting (the default ordering is `orderByKey()`). When not using `orderByKey()`, the second parameter is the key's value.

Because `startAt` is inclusive, you'll also want to use `startAfter` instead when fetching the next "page" of results.

Putting these two recommendations together gives:

```
ref
  .startAfter(lastItemProgrammeName, lastItemId)
  .limitToFirst(6)
  .addChildEventListener(/* ... */);
```

Comment: i am using the firebase there is no startAfter , there are only startAt and endAt , when i use the startAt it is giving me the last item duplicated